# React onClick target.value undefined

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using Antd to generate Tags and I want to modify state using onClick event.

My parent Component (Where I generate a List of Items)

```
onRiskClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
[...]
render() {
return (
[...]
<div className="square risk_orange">
              <RenderingRiskMatrix
                risks={this.state.risks}
                impact="2"
                likelihood="5"
                color="red"
                onRiskClick={this.onRiskClick} <-- passing onRiskClick function as props
              ></RenderingRiskMatrix>
            </div>
```

My Child Function RenderingRiskMatrix

```
<Tooltip key={risk.id} title={risk.name}>
            <Tag
              key={risk.id}
              color={props.color}
              onClick={(event) => props.onRiskClick(event)}
            >
              {risk.id}
            </Tag>
</Tooltip>
```

What I got in console :

```
<span class="ant-tag ant-tag-red" ant-click-animating-without-extra-node="false">R028</span>
undefined
```

which means `e.target` exists and not `e.target.value` which should be R028 no ?

Thanks,

Comment: Where does `Tag` come from? Are you sure it assigns a `value`?

Comment: Tag from ant design https://ant.design/components/tag/, but since there is a value inside <span> it should works no ?

Comment: What do you expect the `value` to be? The API docs from the `Tag` component do not list `onChange` or `value`.

Comment: in e.target I have : `<span class="ant-tag ant-tag-red" ant-click-animating-without-extra-node="false">R028</span>` and I want `R028`

Comment: The answer provided by Jose Manuel Lora Nuñez will work. I have also provided an alternative solution that I think will be more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a simpler way to accomplish your goal. The value you want is a child, not the value. You already have access to the value you want though, so I would use it like this:

```js
<Tooltip key={risk.id} title={risk.name}>
  <Tag
    key={risk.id}
    color={props.color}
    onClick={() => props.onRiskClick(risk.id)}
  >
    {risk.id}
  </Tag>
</Tooltip>
```

Then use it like this:

```js
onRiskClick(value) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

This will be a more flexible solution than accessing the `innerHTML` from the event target. You can now display it any way you want (or even render another component), and you function will still get the value it needs.

Comment: Oh my god, I don't know why I did not think about it.... just passing the value to the function...Thank You !

Comment: @ExploiterZ just for further clarification. Accessing the `value` on an element will look for an attribute called "value". So for instance it would work if the `Tag` rendered something like this: `<span value="R028" />`. But since it renders it as inner html, it will not be accessible by the `value` property.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you already have the element, then to get the content inside the element you need to use `e.target.innerHTML` to get the tag content, other way is using `e.target.textContent` but is not supported on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

you should call `e.persist()` before console.log

If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you should call event.persist() on the event, which will remove the synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be retained by user code.

Comment: Its true that you need to persist the event or assign it to another variable when using it asynchronously, but I dont see any async operations in the question?

Comment: same issue, I got the event.target and an undefined event.target.value

Answer (score 0):

Change your onclick function like this.you need to pass the event data to the function and use the data

```
const onRiskClick = e =>{
    function ....
}
.....
 <RenderingRiskMatrix
                    risks={this.state.risks}
                    impact="2"
                    likelihood="5"
                    color="red"
                    onRiskClick={e=>{
onRiskClick(e)
} <-- passing onRiskClick function as props
                  ></RenderingRiskMatrix>
```

Comment: This is just another way of accomplishing the same thing. Adding an extra arrow function will not change the functionality.

Comment: same issue, I got the event.target and an undefined event.target.value

Answer (score 0):

I found a solved issue about the "undefined" value from e.target.value
here
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4745

the solution was to use **e.currentTarget.value** instead
HTH.